# Hardcoding function parameter yields 5x speed up

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following stored procedure to generate a dynamic query.

Given a list of conditions/filters, it finds all `Visitors` who belong to a given `App`. The `app_id` is passed in as an argument.

If I call the function with an app id, and use this argument in the dynamic query, it runs in around 200ms.

However, if I hardcode the `app_id`, it runs in < 20ms.

Here an example of how I invoke the procedure

```
SELECT id
FROM find_matching_visitors('my_app_id', '{}', '{( field = ''app_name'' and string_value ILIKE ''My awesome app''  )}')
```

Any ideas as ideas as to why?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_matching_visitors(app_id text, default_filters text[], custom_filters text[])
    RETURNS TABLE (
      id varchar
    ) AS
    $body$
    DECLARE
        default_filterstring text;
        custom_filterstring text;
        default_filter_length integer;
        custom_filter_length integer;
        sql VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
        default_filter_length := COALESCE(array_length(default_filters, 1), 0);
        custom_filter_length := COALESCE(array_length(custom_filters, 1), 0);

        default_filterstring := array_to_string(default_filters, ' AND ');
        custom_filterstring := array_to_string(custom_filters, ' OR ');

        IF custom_filterstring = '' or custom_filterstring is null THEN
            custom_filterstring := '1=1';
        END IF;

        IF default_filterstring = '' or default_filterstring is null THEN
            default_filterstring := '1=1';
        END IF;

        sql := format('
                    SELECT v.id FROM visitors v
                    LEFT JOIN trackings t on v.id = t.visitor_id
                    WHERE v.app_id = ''HARDCODED_APP_ID'' and (%s) and (%s)
                    group by v.id

                ', custom_filterstring, default_filterstring, custom_filter_length, custom_filter_length);
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;

    END;
    $body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Analyze without hardcoding app_id

```
Limit  (cost=481.86..481.99 rows=50 width=531) (actual time=163.579..163.581 rows=9 loops=1)
2     ->  Sort  (cost=481.86..484.26 rows=960 width=531) (actual time=163.578..163.579 rows=9 loops=1)
3           Sort Key: v0.last_seen DESC
4           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
5           ->  WindowAgg  (cost=414.62..449.97 rows=960 width=531) (actual time=163.553..163.560 rows=9 loops=1)
6                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=414.62..437.97 rows=960 width=523) (actual time=163.525..163.537 rows=9 loops=1)
7                       Hash Cond: ((find_matching_visitors.id)::text = (v0.id)::text)
8                       ->  Function Scan on find_matching_visitors  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=153.918..153.918 rows=9 loops=1)
9                       ->  Hash  (cost=354.19..354.19 rows=4814 width=523) (actual time=9.578..9.578 rows=4887 loops=1)
10                            Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2145kB
11                            ->  Seq Scan on visitors v0  (cost=0.00..354.19 rows=4814 width=523) (actual time=0.032..4.993 rows=4887 loops=1)
12                                  Filter: ((NOT merged) AND (((type)::text = 'user'::text) OR ((type)::text = 'lead'::text)))
13                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 138
14  Planning time: 1.134 ms
15  Execution time: 163.705 ms
```

Analyze when hardcoding app_id

```
Limit  (cost=481.86..481.99 rows=50 width=531) (actual time=25.890..25.893 rows=9 loops=1)
2     ->  Sort  (cost=481.86..484.26 rows=960 width=531) (actual time=25.888..25.890 rows=9 loops=1)
3           Sort Key: v0.last_seen DESC
4           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
5           ->  WindowAgg  (cost=414.62..449.97 rows=960 width=531) (actual time=25.862..25.870 rows=9 loops=1)
6                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=414.62..437.97 rows=960 width=523) (actual time=25.830..25.841 rows=9 loops=1)
7                       Hash Cond: ((find_matching_visitors.id)::text = (v0.id)::text)
8                       ->  Function Scan on find_matching_visitors  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=15.875..15.876 rows=9 loops=1)
9                       ->  Hash  (cost=354.19..354.19 rows=4814 width=523) (actual time=9.936..9.936 rows=4887 loops=1)
10                            Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2145kB
11                            ->  Seq Scan on visitors v0  (cost=0.00..354.19 rows=4814 width=523) (actual time=0.013..5.232 rows=4887 loops=1)
12                                  Filter: ((NOT merged) AND (((type)::text = 'user'::text) OR ((type)::text = 'lead'::text)))
13                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 138
14  Planning time: 0.772 ms
15  Execution time: 26.006 ms
```

UPDATE 1: Added explain for both cases. NOTE: They're actually the exact same plans, only the time spent varies

UPDATE 2: It turned out that I needed to pass the `app_id` as an argument to the format function, instead of just embedding it directly. This took the query time down to around 20/30ms

Comment: PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Using version 9.5

Comment: What does EXPLAIN ANALYZE have to say?

Comment: @DmitriGoldring Updated post with explain

Answer (score 2):

The hard coded values is important to determine the most optimal query plan.
For example:

```
select * from some_table where id_person=231
select * from some_table where id_person=10
```

When 90% of the some_table has id_person=231 pg uses a full table scan, because that's the fastest.
When 1% of the records has id_person=10 , it uses a index scan.
So the plan used depends on the value of the parameter.

when you using not a hard coded value, e.g.

```
select * from some_table where id_person=?
```

It isn't able to determine the most optimal query plan and the query can be slower.

Comment: As can be seen for the explain analyze, they're using the exact same query plan

Comment: @Tarlen: It's about the execution plan for the statement _inside_ the function, not for the query using the function

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary actually. PostgreSQL (as of 9.2, I think) will re-plan with parameters once it knows them, if it thinks it might get a faster plan. That's why I asked the PostgreSQL version. What happens if you run `PREPARE q(int) AS SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id_person = $1` then `EXPLAIN EXECUTE q(231)` ?